# Rails 4: shallow resource not working with collection in RESTful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a nested resource as such:

```
resource :user, controller: :users do
    # code ...
    resources :profile, controller: :profiles, shallow: true do
        # code ...
        collection do
            get :featured
        end
    end
end
```

The focus is the `featured` action of `profiles`.

The URL this generates is `/user/profile/featured`. I don't understand this because I specified `shallow: true`, yet it's still being nested under `user/`. I want the URL to be `/profile/featured` instead.

If I just do `get :featured` instead of putting it in a collection, I get `/profile/:id/featured`, which is also not what I want.

Comment: `resource :user, controller: :users, shallow: true`

Comment: I just tried that; didn't work – isn't `shallow` meant for a child/nested resource (i.e. you don't use it in the parent, but in the child).

Comment: If you want the URL to be `/profile/featured`, why are you nesting your profile and featured resources inside of user?  By nesting, you are telling Rails that you want to get these resources in the context of a user.

Comment: Most scenarios, it would be `/user/profile/...` but for this particular route, I would prefer it to be `/profile/featured`. It's not that much of an issue (I can simply make a custom route for it), but I wonder why the shallow routing is not being applied here.

Comment: I think it would make sense if I mentioned that I'm experimenting here, and the code above is not my real code (I will either be using `shallow do`, or just, like I said, use a custom route).

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of routes within a given resource: collection routes (i.e. routes on the collection), and member routes  (i.e. routes on individual records). When you specify that a nested route should be shallow, it only keeps routes nested that MUST be nested, and everything else is un-nested. Let's simplify your routes a smidge so we can talk through it better:

```rb
resources :users do
    resources :profiles, shallow: true
end
```

If you take a look at the routes generated by that, you'll notice that the only profile-related routes nested under the user are:

- `GET /users/:user_id/profiles`: Obtain a list of all profiles **for this user**
- `GET /users/:user_id/profiles/new`: Render the page to create a new profile **for this user**
- `POST /users/:user_id/profiles`: Create a new profile **for this user**

Everything else is no longer nested under users. Notice what all of these have in common: **for this user**. This comes back to what I said earlier: Rails only nests *what it must*. The user is an important part of the equation here, and there's no other way that it can be identified (without manual work on your part, anyway). However, once we have a *record*, we have a profile ID we can operate on. We no longer care about the user, and thus we don't need nested routes anymore.

In general, Rails expects that, since you've implied that profiles belong to users, it makes the most sense to only generate routes for operating on the collection within the scope of the user to which they belong. In other words, in most cases, you don't care about fetching the entire collection of profiles, you only care about the profiles for a particular user.

As a result, collection routes *remain nested*. On the other hand, for member routes we have a profile ID to work with, so they are *not* nested.

In your case, you're trying to do something a bit out of the above-described ordinary, so you'll need to create such routes yourself. Hopefully that explains the behavior you're seeing, though.

A final note, in case anyone notices: I used the plural `resources` here, where you actually used `resource`. It doesn't actually matter-- `resource` implies that there's a single user to operate upon when it sees a `/user` route, which is equivalent to the case with `resources` when it sees a `/users/:user_id` route. I used the plural form because I find it a little easier to understand.